# Quantization-aware training in Tensorflow using the highlevel keras api

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, tpu

I built my first covnet using the process described in [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/courses/udacity_intro_to_tensorflow_for_deep_learning/l05c02_dogs_vs_cats_with_augmentation.ipynb). Now I would like to run the model on Googles shiny new edge tpu.

But according to the Model Requirments described [here](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/), I need to use `quantization-aware training (post-training quantization is not supported).` to be able to convert the model into a format that I can use on the EdgeTPU.

How do I modify the example colab to do this quantization-aware training thing?

Comment: While you can quantize the graph via `session = tf.keras.backend.get_session(); tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph(session.graph); session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`, note that Keras API for Tensorflow doesn't support quantization (yet) and it will work only with simple models. You should track those two open issues: [keras #11105](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11105), [tensorflow #27880](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27880).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well because the keras API does not support quantization in the current edition you are left with 3 options:

1. wait for keras to have the required functionality
2. rewrite your model with a different API that has this functionality
3. find a different TPU that does not require you to quantize your data

either way though the solution is not great though.